# increase the amount of symbols by increasing an integer (python)

Tags: python, python-3.8

I am trying to display an indicator for the time taken and i want to show a progressbar.

Heres my current code:

```
time = time * 60
time = time / 100
x = 0
while x < 101:
    per = chr(ord('█') + int(x))
    per_ = chr(ord(' ') + int(100 - x))
    await asyncio.sleep(time)
    pr = (f'\rTime used: |{str(per)}{str(per_)}| {x}%')
    print(pr, end="\r")
    x = x + 1
```

But all i got is weird combination of symbols. I don't really know how to use chr or ord properly

> > Time used: |▐ ↑| 8%

Comment: Can you clarify what result you desire, and what you intend the ``chr(ord(...) + ...)`` expressions to do? Do you want to *repeat* a character x or 100-x times?

Comment: Yes, i want to repeat a character x times. As im learning python i just googled how to do that. Also thats why i said i don't know how to use chr an ord properly

Comment: ``'█' * x`` will repeat ``'█'`` x times.

Comment: that easy? this is a little embarrassing... but thank you really much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chr` and `ord` convert between characters and integers representing that specific character. You don't need to use them here.

Also, `*` is used to repeat a string (and not `+`).

Something like this should work:

```
per = '█' * int(x)
per_ = ' ' * int(100 - x))
```